# Trouble with initial rails gem install on OSX 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, osx-mavericks, libxml2

After a little hastle I have rbenv and ruby installed.  When I try to install rails, I'm failing here:

```
$ gem install rails -v 4.2.3

[....]

checking for main() in -llzma... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

[....]
```

I use macports for my package management and it seems like libxml2 is present (as I expect it would be):

```
$ port list *libxml*
libxml                         @1.8.17         textproc/libxml
libxml2                        @2.9.2          textproc/libxml2
libxmldiff                     @0.2.5          textproc/libxmldiff
libxmlxx                       @1.0.5          textproc/libxmlxx
libxmlxx2                      @2.38.1         textproc/libxmlxx2
p5-libxml-enno                 @1.20.0         perl/p5-libxml-enno
p5-libxml-perl                 @0.80.0         perl/p5-libxml-perl
p5-xml-libxml                  @2.12.300       perl/p5-xml-libxml
p5-xml-libxml-simple           @0.950.0        perl/p5-xml-libxml-simple
p5-xml-rss-libxml              @0.310.500      perl/p5-xml-rss-libxml
p5.16-libxml-enno              @1.20.0         perl/p5-graveyard
p5.16-libxml-perl              @0.80.0         perl/p5-graveyard
p5.16-xml-libxml               @2.12.300       perl/p5-graveyard
p5.16-xml-libxml-simple        @0.950.0        perl/p5-graveyard
p5.16-xml-rss-libxml           @0.310.500      perl/p5-graveyard
p5.18-libxml-enno              @1.20.0         perl/p5-graveyard
p5.18-libxml-perl              @0.80.0         perl/p5-graveyard
p5.18-xml-libxml               @2.12.300       perl/p5-graveyard
p5.18-xml-libxml-simple        @0.950.0        perl/p5-graveyard
p5.18-xml-rss-libxml           @0.310.500      perl/p5-graveyard
p5.20-libxml-enno              @1.20.0         perl/p5-graveyard
p5.20-libxml-perl              @0.80.0         perl/p5-graveyard
p5.20-xml-libxml               @2.12.300       perl/p5-graveyard
p5.20-xml-libxml-simple        @0.950.0        perl/p5-graveyard
p5.20-xml-rss-libxml           @0.310.500      perl/p5-graveyard
p5.22-libxml-enno              @1.20.0         perl/p5-libxml-enno
p5.22-libxml-perl              @0.80.0         perl/p5-libxml-perl
p5.22-xml-libxml               @2.12.300       perl/p5-xml-libxml
p5.22-xml-libxml-simple        @0.950.0        perl/p5-xml-libxml-simple
p5.22-xml-rss-libxml           @0.310.500      perl/p5-xml-rss-libxml
py-libxml2                     @2.9.2          python/py-libxml2
py24-libxml2                   @2.9.2          python/py-graveyard
py25-libxml2                   @2.9.2          python/py-graveyard
py26-libxml2                   @2.9.2          python/py-graveyard
py27-libxml2                   @2.9.2          python/py-libxml2
py34-libxml2                   @2.9.2          python/py-libxml2
py35-libxml2                   @2.9.2          python/py-libxml2
rb-libxml2                     @2.3.4          ruby/rb-libxml2
```

Comment: Try installing it as: gem install rails -v 4.2.3 -- --use-system-libraries

Comment: Thanks!  That was totally the solution.  If you make it an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing it as:

`gem install rails -v 4.2.3 -- --use-system-libraries`

Answer (score 0):

What when you type `which libxml2` it should return the path to the binary.

If it does not update your `$PATH` in your `~/.bash_profile`. A quick command to do that is:

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

followed by a:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

My recommendation would be for you to switch to [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) for package management on OSX along with a switch to [RVM](https://rvm.io/) for ruby management.

Comment: Those paths are already included in my $PATH env var.  Other ports work fine.  I'll look into Homebrew & RVM in the future though - thanks.